# Search a nested list against items from alternative list, returning subsets that contain partial match

Tags: python, regex, list, enumerate

Say I have two lists such as:

```
NestedLst = ['1234567', 'abc456789', ['cde678945']]
SearchLst = ['123', 'cde']
```

How do I search the nested list for any partial matches with any of the items of the search list and return for each search item the subset list. So in this case I want the output to be:

```
['1234567', 'abc456789', ['cde678945']] and ['cde678945']
```

I have tried doing the below:

```
    indices = []

for eachItem in SearchLst:
    for i, elem in enumerate(NestedLst):
        if eachItem in elem:
            indices.append(i)

print indices
```

but this always returns `[0]`. Any help would be much appreciated. As I am new to Python a full explanation of the code would be very helpful for me to learn.

Thankyou

Below is an example nested list in practice:

```
[['BMNH833953:0.16529463651919140688', [[['BMNH833883:0.22945757727367316336', ['BMNH724182a:0.18028180766761139897', ['BMNH724182b:0.21469677818346077913', 'BMNH724082:0.54350916483644962085'], ':0.00654573856803835914'], ':0.04530853441176059537'], ':0.02416511342888815264', [[['BMNH794142:0.21236619242575086042', ['BMNH743008:0.13421900772403019819', 'BMNH724591:0.14957653992840658219'], ':0.02592135486124686958'], ':0.02477670174791116522', 'BMNH703458a:0.22983459269245612444'], ':0.00000328449424529074', 'BMNH703458b:0.29776257618061197086'], ':0.09881729077887969892'], ':0.02257522897558370684', 'BMNH833928:0.21599133163597591945'], ':0.02365043128986757739', 'BMNH724053:0.16069861523756587274'], ':0.0;\n']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using a method and recursion:

```
NestedLst = ['1234567', 'abc456789', ['cde678945']]
SearchLst = ['123', 'cde']

def get_list(a,b):
    for i in b:
        if type(i)==list:          #if this is a nested list, do the same function for the contents of that list, returning that list if it meets the conditions.
            return get_list(a,i)
        elif a in i:               #if element in list is not a nested list, just do normal check for containment using in
            return b
    return []

x = [get_list(i,NestedLst) for i in SearchLst]  #just calls the function for all search terms

for k in x:
    print k

[OUTPUT]
['1234567', 'abc456789', ['cde678945']]
['cde678945']
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thankyou, could you comment the code to explain what each bit does. I understand most of it but not if type(i)==list for example

Comment: @PaulBarr, Added comment. Hope it helps now.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this code for the new list I have added to my question when searching for matches of '0.00000328449424529074'but I always get a return of empty lists [], do you know why this may be?

Comment: @PaulBarr, I'm working it through. It might take some time. Sorry.

Comment: @PaulBarr, I think it works now. Here is the updated sript: http://repl.it/Rcw/2. Please let me know if you are successful now.

Comment: Thankyou It works perfectly, what edit did you make? You have answered many of my questions on SO now! Thank you for all your help

Comment: @PaulBarr, I fixed the problem with the function simply returning an empty list if nothing was found in that depth. It was not returning back to a higher list level. I fixed that by creating a list of matches and returning the list at the end instead of straightaway.

Comment: It does seem to return strange results if the Search list is larger, such as: ['0.00654573856803835914', '0.04530853441176059537', '0.02416511342888815264', '0.02592135486124686958', '0.02477670174791116522', '0.00000328449424529074', '0.02257522897558370684', '0.02365043128986757739'] but it works well for small search lists

Comment: @PaulBarr, Ah. I think I know why. It has to do with python's least astonishment question on stackoverflow. Change to `x = [get_list(i,NestedLst, []) for i in SearchLst]` and tell me if that works

Comment: @PaulBarr, Great! Really glad with how this has turned out. Great question by the way.